# how to post message on facebook wall, I can login but can't post anything?

Tags: android, facebook

I can able to login, but facing difficulty in posting message on facebook wall. can somebody give me the possible resolutions?

Comment: please be more specific. are you getting any errors? can you show us some code you think might be wrong?

Comment: hey, if you don't get what I am asking, please don't vote down. Everybody tries the sample code given at facebook developer website to integrate with android which is default thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the link below:
http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/290-facebook-integration-in-your-android-application
Just, don't forget to add app ID in your code. And its the efficient code you can get...:)